How to list the data under a collection in a Qdrant server?
Assume that I have saved 10 texts with embeddings into a collection of a Qdrant server, can a Qdrant client list the data in that collection?
For example, the data and embeddings are as follows.

text_1, embedding_1
text_2, embedding_2
text_3, embedding_3
...

Can a Quant client show the following lines to the user?

text_1
text_2
text_3
...

I have browsed its document at https://qdrant.tech/documentation/. Seems to me that the client can  do a similarity search but not list the data. Any suggestion?

You can use Qdrant's scroll API to get your points with the payload. It also supports filtering if needed.
You can refer to the documentation at https://qdrant.tech/documentation/concepts/points/#scroll-points

you can get the payload and the embeddings from the collection using client.scroll()
